# Arduino Installation Guide for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Tags: arduino, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm following an [installation guide for Arduino](http://www.pluggy.me.uk/arduino-ubuntu/). I have Arduino UNO rev3 and ubuntu 64bit

The guide refers to Synaptic Package manager to install software. But it doesn't seem to be available in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Should I install the list of software components via Ubuntu software center? Or should I install the Synaptic Package manager? (e.g. http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3610)

Is there any difference between the two installation applications?

Comment: Software center should work fine if you find the software there. You can also use apt on the command line

Comment: Is there no difference in the up-to-date-ness of repositories? Or refer apt-get, software center and synaptic all to the same repo?

Comment: According to this [http://arduino.cc/playground/Linux/Ubuntu](http://arduino.cc/playground/Linux/Ubuntu) the Ubuntu repositories are way behind and don't even support the newest Arduino boards

Comment: @hsmit, yes they all do use the same information from the repositories specified under /etc/apt

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble syncing processing and arduino in 12.04.
I installed arduino in every possible way imaginable:  from the website, from synaptic/software-centre, from apt-get... etc and it just wouldn't run.

If you are having trouble 'running' it , go to a terminal and run it there to see the problem. Post details.

In my case I got java headlessexceptions errors, which I concluded was because 12.04 didn't have any JAVA stuff installed? Can you believe it! It came to me as a shock, but oh well:

Go to synaptic and get the following packages:
java-common, openjdk-7/6, java-wrappers, libjaxme-java, default-jre, defaul-jdk, libbsf-java, default-jre-headless, openjdk-6-jre-headless

I am sorry if some of these are irrelevant to arduino, I just went on a 'click-on-jdk' stuff spree and got it to work :) Processing and Arduino run like a charm now!

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you use Synaptic or a similar package manager, it should install all the dependencies automatically. I've just installed Arduino from Synaptic and its downloaded and installed most of the libraries you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial for setting up Arduino in Ubuntu. I found this one to be the most helpful. [Install Arduino IDE in Ubuntu.](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/install-arduino-ubuntu/)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way to get the Arduino IDE on Linux is to download the software from this page http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software (either the 32bit or 64bit linux version depending on your system)

After you download it all you have to do is extract the archive and run the executable called "arduino"

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to intall the IDE, but I think that all dependencies like gcc-avr, avr-libc etc must be installed first. So which repository should I use then? Universe?

Comment: Yes those packages are located int the Universe repo.You can use `sudo apt-get install gcc-avr avr-libc`

Comment: for completeness: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre avr-libc gcc-avr`

Answer (score 0):

For installing Arduino 1.0 in Precise there is no difference between using Synaptic or Software Center, they will both install including dependancies. The biggest difference is the user interface and that Software Center allows for purchasing some additional software, they are both using your repos defined in /etc/apt/sources.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/arduino/
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/

Answer (score 0):

Installing Arduino on Linux is a little bit harder than the same installation on Windows or Mac. A wide list with tutorials for [Arduino installation on Linux](http://www.intorobotics.com/resources-and-tutorials-to-start-working-with-arduino-boards/) could be a good help for you. Also, you can check this guide for arduino installation http://playground.arduino.cc//Learning/Linux

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install arduino for ubuntu is with terminal.
The first line command you have to write is:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino
```

This will update your ubuntu packages and also install the arduino package. Then type:

```
tar -xvzf filename.tar.xz
```

Then you have to go to the directory Downloads (cd Downloads), and next to the arduino directory (cd filename).

Finally to run arduino, once you are inside the arduino directory you type:

```
./arduino
```

It will run the program.

Comment: Tunaki, How have you done this? I don't know how to do it, can you explain me please!